# How can I install modules with Composer?

Tags: craft3, composer, modules

Installing a Craft 3 plugin via Composer is pretty simple. You require the package, update Composer, and install it via the CMS.

My circumstances require that our company use a private Module on all projects. But installing the package via Composer always puts the Module into the default `vendor` directory.

So how can I install a module into the modules folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Craft Plugins require that a `"type":"craft-plugin"` property is defined in each `composer.json` file. Composer refers to this to help manage and install the plugin. Craft Modules do not currently have this support.

You can see all package types that Composer Installer supports [here](https://github.com/composer/installers#current-supported-package-types). There is still a way to achieve what you're trying to do though...

[Composer Installers Extender](https://github.com/oomphinc/composer-installers-extender) allows you to create your own custom package type. So we could create `craft-module` ourselves. Just make sure your module has this `"type":"craft-module"` in it's `composer.json`

Now we can define some `extra` settings that tell Composer to put the modules into the modules directory. Incorporate the following into your projects `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
  "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^1.1",
  "vendorname/modulename": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "modules\\": "modules/",
    "modules\\modulename\\": "modules/modulename/module/"
  }
},
"extra": {
  "installer-types": ["craft-module"],
  "installer-paths": {
    "modules/{$name}": ["type:craft-module"]
  }
},
```

*Note: Make sure your module no longer exists in your vendor directory as you may be hit with some potential conflict warnings.*