# Installing module via composer

Tags: composer, modules

I followed [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26642/how-can-i-install-modules-with-composer) like:

```
...
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:jorgeanzola/mymodule.git"
}
],
...

"require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.0.0",
    ...
    "jorgeanzola/mymodule": "^1.0.0"
},

...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        ...
        "modules\\mymodule\\": "modules/mymodule/src/",
    }
},
...

"extra": {
  "installer-types": ["craft-module"],
  "installer-paths": {
    "modules/mymodule": ["type:craft-module"]
  }
},
...
```

When I do a `composer install`, I get this error:

**[RuntimeException]

craft/plugins/schematic/ does not exist and could not be created.**

In my module I don't do anything with Schematic. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is Schematic required in your main Composer file? This could be a permission thing, where Composer tries to install Schematic but the vendor folder permissions are wrong. I always try to completely remove the vendor folder and run composer install again.